# Python Webscraping character encoding issues

Tags: python, html, encoding, web-scraping, string-formatting

I am a recent graduate, who just began self learning about python webscraping and, just for fun, I am attempting to build a script that allows me to store the names, episodes and episode description of Anime shows from a particular website, using python requests, re and other relevant modules.

I have managed to get the webscraping aspect of script working, which is openning the necessary urls and retreiving relevant data, however, one major issue I continuosly cant overcome are different encodings and special html character decoding contained within the names of some of the shows.

After going through several stack overflow websites I have come up with the following solutions for trying to sort out this issue of decoding html characters and also fixing of encoding:

```
try:
    # Python 2.6-2.7 
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
    
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
    
decodeHTMLSpecialChar   = HTMLParser()
    
def whatisthis(s):     
    # This function checks to see if a given string is an ordinary string, unicode encoded string or not a string at all
    
    if isinstance(s, str):
        return "ordinary string"
    elif isinstance(s, unicode):
        return "unicode string"
    else:
        return "not a string"
    
def DecodeHTMLAndFixEncoding(string_data):
    string_data = decodeHTMLSpecialChar.unescape(string_data)
    encoding_check = whatisthis(string_data)
        
    if encoding_check != "ordinary string": 
        string_data = string_data.encode("utf-8")
    
    return string_data
```

All of the above code I obtained from various different stack overflow solutions.

Although this fixed most of the encoding issues I faced, today I found out other issues, that I just cant seem to figure out how to solve.

Below are the 2 different strings that are resulting to python string encoding errors or are not appropriately converting html special characters.

## ISSUE CASE 1:

```
string1 = "Musekinin Galaxy☆Tylor" 
print(DecodeHTMLAndFixEncoding(string1))
#...Results to "Musekinin Galaxy☆Tylor", however, because I have the name stored as a key within a dictionary to help check if the name has already been stored or not, when referencing the key, I get the following error:

Error Type: <type 'exceptions.KeyError'>
Error Contents: ('Musekinin Galaxy\xe2\x98\x86Tylor',)
```

The dictionary where i store the data is in the following format:

```
data = {show name (Key):
           {
            description (Key2) : "Overall Description for the show"
            show episode name (Key) : "Description for episode"
           }
       }
```

## ISSUE CASE 2:

```
string2 = "Knight&#039;s &amp;#038; Magic"
print(DecodeHTMLAndFixEncoding(string2))
Results to... "Knight's &#038; Magic"

# Although this kind of works it should have resulted to "Knight's & Magic".
```

I have tried my best to explain the issue I face here, my main question essentially is, is there a simple solution to:

- firstly allow me to remove symbols, emojis, etc. from a string to ensure it can be used a dictionary key, and can later be easily referenced without any issues, and
- secondly, a better solution than html parser to decode special html character encodings such as the issue shown in issue case 2

My last request is, I would prefer a solution using stock python provided default libraries or modules in contrast to external ones, such as beutifulsoup and such. However, If you feel they are some helpful external modules that can help me, then please feel free to show me those as well.

Comment: I thought the unescape function is within html and not html.parser [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#module-html). Which version of python are you using? EDIT: `HTMLParser.handle_charref()` have you tried this?

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx Thankyou for your reply. I am using Python Version 2.7.11. Unfortunately when I use import html, i get an import error, saying the library does not exist. 

Also I tried changing to HTMLParser.handle_charref and I still get the same output as I got on ISSUE CASE 2. Not sure why, it doesnt want to convert: 

'&amp;#038;' to &, instead it converts it to: &#038;

Comment: So, &amp = &, but &#038 is also &. Perhaps try doing charref twice? Or you could blacklist #038 manually (but would be bad idea if a website decides not to use &amp;

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx Tried it twice, didnt work, But I think i just figured it out thanks to what you said. it converted '&amp;#038;' to '&#038;' so just realised the &amp; was converted to & and the remaining #038; was left, resulting to &#038; so for now just using .replace("#038;", ""), So hopefully that takes care of ISSUE 2, but any solution for ISSUE 1, is there a way i can just get rid of the symbols to allow me to use the name as dictionary key without issues.

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx Sorry just tried to run the code with the replace bit, but it didnt replace anything, the output still remained the same, so not sure whats going on. Can python replace function not replace special character code?

Comment: str.replace() will return another string. make sure you're saving that value back into str or some other variable too

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx Sory for late reply. I am well aware of the need to re-store the item when using string.replace()... Its just python acting up, not returning the modified string, n now to fix it after the string was returned, i have used str() on the returned string and there after using replace() worked

Comment: Alright. Sorry for not being able to solve your question directly. Hope everything is okay now!

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx Thats ok, I really appreciate the help, although my fix works, i feel if other symbols or emoticons are used in the future, i will have to hardcode them to be replaced aswell in the future. Ohh well, its just a side project so prob wouldnt even need it for that long, so thanks once again for all the support :).

Comment: Most other symbols should be written as &#xxx; and they will be translated with HTMLparser. This is just an exception because the & needs to be escaped. but for some reason the API you're using is leaving an incompleted symbol with the &amp; If you need a non-hardcoded solution, you should use beautifulsoup.

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx Thank you soo much for all the support. I see what you mean. I havent looked at beautifulsoup yet, but I am aware of it being a useful 3rd party module used to aid with webscrapping. I will attempt to use it when I consider doing another project. Once again Thank you very much.